How do I make Tkinter not block Jupyter like Matplotlib does?
I have matplotlib-based GUI app which takes inputs and plots graphs. It works just fine except that the UI is abysmally non-responsive (seconds before it reacts to mouse clicks or keyboard, on a fairly powerful windows box). I start it from a Jupyter notebook with %matplotlib qt, the GUI shows up, and the notebook is not blocked, so I can query and modify the underlying matplotlib objects interactively.
I want the same behavior from tkinter.ttk, but Tk.mainloop blocks. Is there a way around this?

GUIs weren't created for interactive modifications.

In modern Jupyter, I doubt you really want/need to be using %matplotlib qt. If you have really updated Jupyter, you want to install ipympl and use %matplotlib ipympl, see here. It works for all sorts of things including animations, but you wouldn't know it from the examples in the documentation I linked to. (I don't know why it lacks that important example at this time.) If you share more of what you are trying to make interactive/updateable in a new post, I probably can help you get your approaches modernized.

@Wayne: I want a GUI app. Yes, ipympl looks interesting - interactive inline plot, much better than inline, thank you! But this is not what I need for the purposes of this question.

You specifically asked about Jupyter in the title and post. Things like ipympl, ipywidgets, and Voila or other flavors of modern app-building software, such as JupyterDash, for use with Jupyter Notebook files has been built to fit this need and work with current flavors of JupyterLab (versions late 3 and now 4) and Jupyter Notebook version 7+.
